Angular ViewChild not initialized for child standalone component
I have a parent component marked as standalone.This consumes another child component which is also standalone. Both the parent and child display successfully.
However, the ViewChild variable is never initialised even on AfterViewInit.
This is an issue only when using standalone components - note whole app is standalone.
Has anyone experienced the same issue and resolved?
Using Angular CLI 16.2.11
Here is some pseudo code where I would expect to be able to call the method DoSomething on the child.

parent.html

<div>My main page</div>
<app-child></app-child>

child.html

<div>I am the child</div>


parent.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ChildComponent],
  templateUrl: './parent.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.scss']
})

export class parent  implements AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild(ChildComponent)
myChildComponent!: ChildComponent;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    // this is always undefined
  console.log(this.myChildComponent);
  
  this.myChildComponent.doSomething();
}


child.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './child.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.scss']
})

export class child  {

    public doSomething() : void{
    }
}


can u transfer ur pseudo code to a stackblitz example

@RussellThomson Issue not Reproducible stackblitz

Thank you Naren you are correct - my cut down version does not exhibit the issue. My apologies - will need to delve down further why it is not happening in the real project.

Russel, see the classname of your components export class child?, I imagine should be export class ChildComponent. Check also if your child is under a *ngIf

It appears the ViewChild ref is being set but after the AfterViewInit within the 'real' code, the child is in a popup window which when closing does have the value assigned.
I am guessing the pipeline just hasn't got there yet - in the code being used it would be better described as a grandparent, parent, child from the main.ts. Just makes it harder to ascertain binding value availability.

do you use a lib for the popup? if not put the business logic into a external services and call them from the component and feed them with the values from the popup component
